# Domain User Access to SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 on IIS7

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssrs

What are the required steps to properly allow domain users access to reports via the Reporting Services web site?

I've tried to give domain users access both through the site itself and through Management Studio, but whenever a user tries to access the site, they are prompted by the browser for their credentials, but they are not able to log in.

I know that this shouldn't be difficult to do!

**UPDATE: SSRS site is running on IIS7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't think of this before but I:

- Added desired domain users to the "SQLServer2005ReportServerUser*$InstanceName*" group on the Windows 2008 machine running SQL Server Reporting Services

AND now users are able to access the reporting services site.

Answer (score 2):

Browse to http://servername/Reports/.  Go to the Properties tab and add New Role Assignments as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for replying; however, I have already done this, and whenever the user tries to access the RS site, they cannot obtain access. No matter how many times they correctly enter their credentials, the log in dialog continues to appear.

Comment: Then an admin, who does have access to the site, needs to add those users to the 'Browers' role. Try this.

Comment: I've done that as well. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe it is an IIS7 thing. I don't have much experience with it. I work mostly with IIS6.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a lot of IIS7 experience, but have you checked the Reports and ReportServer virtual directories in IIS and made sure they are set up for Integrated Windows Auth?

Comment: Yes. They both have Windows Authentication enabled. Thanks for the reply.